# Select float from MySQL with correct precision

Tags: php, mysql

Common trouble that I've searched and read about and still stuck.

I have a table with trades, where trade price is declared as float. I cant' use decimal because different stocks have different precision in their price.

If a look at the table via phpMyAdmin, all numbers look correct - as they were inserted, as you can see on screenshot below, price (p) is 0.709 which is correct.

[image]

But when I select that trade from table using regular zend framework, I get price which is **0.70899999141693**

How can I make a select which works same as MyAdmin select does? And receive number with correct precision? **If myAdmin does the job, it can be possible in zend also, am I right**?

**EDIT: I can't use `ROUND` and I cant use `DECIMAL` because I don't know correct precision.
e.g. price of Apple has 2 decimals in precision, but price of VTB Bank has 6 decimal in precision**

**EDIT2: Here are more examples on same select within myAdmin and zend.**

Trade 8838397 was made by price 0.01156. I've inserted it in database and that's what I get in myAdmin:

[image]

If I select it with php, I get this:

[image]

I assume, myAdmin somehow **guesses** precision and does it really good. How???

Comment: Why not use a decimal precision (or is it scale) high enough to handle the worst case?

Comment: Tricky thing.. this is just how MySQL works. The higher the number, the less precise your calculations will be when using FLOAT|DECIMAL types. DECIMAL field type can be your solution, but you already wrote you can't use it.

Comment: Is the p column always a number below 0?

Comment: You could go for an int and create another column where you write down the precision of the first int. Finding a way to just use ints seems safest to do.

Comment: Yes, I can store precision separately, but how myAdmin does the job without it?

Comment: @Benz, price differs a lot. Sometimes it below 1, sometime not. Sometimes it can be an integer, sometimes decimal

Comment: In my comment I said FLOAT|DECIMAL.. But I ment FLOAT|DOUBLE ;). @ProstoTrader I'm curious how to overcome this problem when you are not able to use DECIMAL. Definently a favorit :)

Comment: MyAdmin somehow already solved it, I just can't undertand how...

Comment: PHP does not have a native decimal datatype, so your numbers are converted to floats no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Quote "I have a table with trades, where trade price is declared as float. I cant' use decimal because different stocks have different precision in their price."

I daresay this is nonsense. If you want precise data then use a precise type. You would only use float if the values exceeded the range DECIMAL offers, which is not the case here. DECIMAL(65,30) handles values with up to 30 digital places. That should be enough for all your values, I guess.

I suppose you are mixing internal storage with data display here. If the number of decimal places is an information needed, then store this information:

```
trade_id  office  price  precision
12345678  123456  0,709  4
```

A query:

```
select trade_id, office, round(price, precision) as price
from trades;
```

Result:

```
trade_id  office  price
12345678  123456  0,7090
```

EDIT: As to "MyAdmin somehow already solved it, I just can't undertand how":

It doesn't. I doubt that it will display 0.120 for an entered 0.120 and 0.12000 for an entered 0.12000. The dbms will store the same float value for both and phpMyAdmin has no way of telling they are to be treated differently. The only thing that phpMyAdmin probably does is to round to a maximum number of decimal places, say 6. `select round( 0.70899999141693 , 6)` results in 0.709.

Comment: I don't care about precision internally, it only matters, when I display trades to client. Php MyAdmin **can** display my table without any additional columns and mess with selects (which will slow down database).
Here is screenshot from MyAdmin, when I browse trades table. As you can see, all numbers displayed with correct precision...http://take.ms/uFKvq

Comment: 0.70899999141693 myAdmin rounds to 0.709, but 0,011559999547899 it rounds to 0.01156. And both numbers **ARE** correct.

Comment: So they are not using round to get to a maximum of n decimal places, but cast: `cast(0.70899999141693 as decimal(65,6))` = 0.709, `cast(0.011559999547899 as decimal(65,6))` = 0.01156.

Comment: nope, doesn't work: CAST(p as DECIMAL(65,6)) as p => 0.529000, 3.000000, 0.039500, 0.689000 - so, it works the same as ROUND...

Comment: Well, I don't know what values you expected instead. Aren't 0.529, 3, 0.0395 and 0.689 the values you stored? I think you should make a fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/ to provide some test base. Anyhow, you would have no problem at all right now, trying to restore the original values, had you stored the precise values (decimal) instead of approximations (float).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `round` function:

```
select round(p, 3) as p from table_name;
```

Comment: I cant, because I don't know precision - it is different for each stock

Comment: Who does know the precision then? Where is the information about it? You need to know it to select it. If it's different for each stock - how do you know that?

Comment: When trade arrives from exchange, it has known and correct precision. I insert it to mySql and loose precision. It's ok, but myAdmin somehow **knows** how to round each number. The question is - how??